# How to click on few enabled elements out of many

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Being a novice to selenium can i have someone to help me with my selenium test.

I have a seat selection page which got a number of seats with available and not available seats option (enabled & disabled). Out of all seats, I want to select 2 available seats only. All seats sharing the same id class. Can someone help me on how i can click one by one on available seats only?

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBRuI.png][1]

Comment: I have attached a seat selection page for a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Java.

First of, make an XPATH that identifies all the seats.

Get the count of seats and then loop over each element.

```
int count = driver.findElements(By.xpath("XPATH")).size();
for (int i=1; i <= count; i++){
    // now make an unique XPATH element using brackets 
    WebElement element = driver.finElement(By.xpath("(XPATH)[i]"));
    if (element.isEnabled()){
        element.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Naveen for your time and help. 

In your above code, it selects all available seats but what if I only want to select 2 available seats out of few available seats. I guess i need to run through another for loop after   WebElement element = driver.finElement(By.xpath("(XPATH)[i]")); to store all available seats and then it selects/click two available seats and break the loop...Correct ??

Would you be able to extend your code to achieve my requirement?

Comment: correct. there should be some difference between the available and non available seat element attributes (either Class/ID). Identify which attribute is differing and you can then go on loop to get the attribute and click only when you match the available seats.